# Kotlin code not auto-importing "revolutpay" and "revolutpayments" library in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, android-studio

I'm working on an Android project in Kotlin and Flutter using Android Studio. I recently added the "revolutpay" and "revolutpayments" library as a dependency in my build.gradle file like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.revolut:revolutpayments:1.0.0"
    implementation "com.revolut:revolutpay:2.2"
}
```

[image]

import like:

```
import com.revolut.revolutpay.api.RevolutPayEnvironment
import com.revolut.revolutpay.api.revolutPay
import com.revolut.revolutpayments.RevolutPayments
```

are working completely fine when I debug but the thing is that I can't auto import in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Android module in seperate Android studio and sync your project.
If you right click on the android module you might see **Open Android module in Android Studio**.

The issue might be because currently flutter project is opened and android studio might not have indexed your dependency files.

For more info on this read here

https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/android-studio#android-ide